# what filtering options are supported MS graph api (List used) - Javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, filter, microsoft-graph

I'm working on a script and I can call the below Graph API endpoint.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/insights/used
```

without any issue. But I would like to use filter like so:

```
var srchStr = "ABC" - Name of site
     
graphEndPoint: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/insights/used?$filter=ResourceVisualization/containerDisplayName eq '"+ srchStr + "'"

graphEndPoint:"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/insights/used?$filter=substringof('"+ srchStr + "', ResourceVisualization/containerDisplayName)"
```

But I keep getting error:

```
{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Invalid filter clause","innerError
```

My goal is to  list the documents that a user has viewed or modified for a specific document library.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot apply filter query based on the `ContainerDisplayName` property.

Also, `ContainerDisplayName` property does not provide the name of specific **document library**. It is:

> A string describing where the item is stored. For example, the name of a SharePoint site or the user name identifying the owner of the OneDrive storing the item.

**Source**: [resourceVisualization resource type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/insights-resourcevisualization?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)

---

Also, The `contains` or `substringof` string operator is currently not supported on any Microsoft Graph resources.

**Source**: [Use query parameters to customize responses](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters)

---

Currently, you can filter on `containerType` property, but it will only tell you if the file is stored in SharePoint site or OneDrive for Business.

Example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/insights/used?$filter=ResourceVisualization/containerType eq 'Site'
```

Comment: Thanks guys but its rather unfortunate. As i could have used the containerWebUrl with contain to get the document library name. 
Are there any other options

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of suggesting to use `containerWebUrl` for filtering. But unfortunately graph API does not support `contains` operator as of now. Also, `used` endpoint does not support `$search` :(

Answer (score 1):

We cannot filter on the property 'ContainerDisplayName'.

I did a test in Graph explorer and got this error: `"The property 'ContainerDisplayName' does not support filtering."`

[image]

Comment: Thanks Michael.
But do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Figured another way out. Tanks all